# Oracle undo tablespace

Tags: sql, oracle, database-administration

I  used toad to connect to Oracle, issued  a select query and while exiting it asked to issue commit or rollback. I pressed the escape key and the message box disappeared. Then I ended the connection. Will this cause any problems to the tables I queried? Will it cause the undo tablespace or rollback segment to go out of control?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the Oracle PMON (Process Monitor) process will handle. If a session is terminated in a disorderly manner, then the session will be left in a state that must be cleared up. The PMON process will then roll back any active transactions.

So to answer your question: No, your transaction is no longer active and all your changes were rolled back (if you did not explicitly commit).